# How to get value from checkbox?

Tags: angular, angular7

Following is my template:

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="updateCategory($event)" value="Education" name="Education" id=""> Education
```

when user check the box ( true ) I require to get the 'Education' as value in change event. how to get that.

this is required for filter purpose.

On console I am not getting value:

```
updateCategory(event){
        console.log('event', event); //?
    }
```

Comment: `event.target.value`

Comment: if you want "make something" use change as everybody say you, but it's only to make visible or not something or get the value, why not use [(ngModel)]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `event.target.value` for value and `event.target.checked` for checkbox selected or not selected.

```
updateCategory(event){
    console.log('event', event.target.value);
    console.log('event', event.target.checked);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.target.value`

```
  updateCategory(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the value like this:

```
updateCategory(event){
  console.log('event', event.target.value);
}
```